# Serialization and deserialization of an object between C# and Python with protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have an object which I want to serialize with C# (protobuf-net) and after that to deserialize it with Python and vice-versa. But I stuck on couple of problems. The first one is that some of the child objects doubles the name of some enum items and some enums items have the same names, too.

> Note that enum values use C++ scoping rules, meaning that enum values
>   are siblings of their type, not children of it`

Is there a way to set something like an alias name which to be mapped to the original object property, so the object to be serialized with the alias name, but when deserialized the alias to be mapped to the real property name?

**Update**

After more digging what I want is the equivalent of `[ProtoEnum(Name="My_Custom_Name")]` for RuntimeTypeModel.

Comment: Hiya. Names don't exist in the protobuf data, so I assume the problem here is actually when using `GetProto` or similar? Everything that can be specified via attributes should also be possible to set via RuntimeTypeModel - I'm not at a PC right now, but I can check later - but there should be some kind of `Name` or similar that is what you are after.

Comment: The only think I found is how to change the enum values in runtime (https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/4b239629f5f9dbe4770a497f2c81465ab0669504/src/Examples/Issues/SO13783894.cs#L38). What I'm trying to do is to change the name of the enum item. There is `RuntimeTypeModel.Name` attribute, but if I set it changes the name of the enum type, not it child element.